# TCP/IP Подключение по HTTPS протоколу (скорость post отправки)

Tags: c#, post, get, tcp, tcp-ip

Всем привет, нужен очень быстрый запрос и моментальный ответ так чтобы запрос прилетал быстрее всех)
На обычных HttpResponseMessage ответ идёт медленно и другие люди успевают забрать нужную мне заявку (тоже бот на апи поставили). Вопрос как оптимизировать скорость работы скрипта и что может увеличить ответ так чтобы это было максимально быстро. Нашел информацию что сокеты работают гораздо быстрее. Написал такой вот код. Но мне приходит ответ что я пытаюсь отправить http запрос по https протоколу, что нужно сделать? Это вообще возможно или я иду не в том направлении?

```
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://site.com/api/getOrders/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", TokenUse);

        TcpClient ClientTcp = new TcpClient();
        ClientTcp.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("111.111.11.11"), 443);
        string postDataAsString = @"GET /api/getExchangeOrders/?amount=100&page_number=1 HTTP/1.1" + 
       Environment.NewLine +
       "Host: 111.111.11.11" + Environment.NewLine +
       "Authorization: "+ TokenUse + Environment.NewLine +
       Environment.NewLine +
       Environment.NewLine +
       "P270=2&sid=3dc7588be24f";
        byte[] postDataBinary = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postDataAsString);

        // make post request
        ClientTcp.Client.Send(postDataBinary);

        // get response
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int lengthOfResponse = ClientTcp.Client.Receive(bytes);

        var resp = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, lengthOfResponse);
        Console.WriteLine(resp);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Тормозит установление нового соединения, а внутри уже установленного коннекта по https все работает быстро

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но мне приходит ответ что я пытаюсь отправить http запрос по https протоколу, что нужно сделать?

Изучить как работает HTTPS в первую очередь, сначала надо отправить запрос CONNECT а не GET и установить TLS канал шифрования, для этого есть класс `SslStream`. В общем, всё уже написано профессионалами, и `HttpClient` - очень быстрый клиент.

Чтобы `HttpClient` работал быстро, надо уметь его использовать.

- Использовать .NET 6 или новее, так как реализация быстрого `SocketsHttpHandler` для `HttpClient` есть только там
- Использовать HTTP/2. Если сервер поддерживает, это сильно ускорит отклик.
- Использовать GZip cжатие для ответов
- Не пересоздавать `HttpClient` на каждое соединение, тогда открытые соединения будут переиспользоваться и время отклика станет минимальным

```
private static readonly HttpClient client = CreateClient("123");

private static HttpClient CreateClient(string apiToken)
{
    HttpClient client = new(new HttpClientHandler
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.All
    }) 
    { 
        DefaultRequestVersion = HttpVersion.Version20,
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://site.com/api/")
    };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiToken);
    return client;
}

private static Task<string> GetOrdersAsync()
{
    return client.GetStringAsync("getExchangeOrders/?amount=100&page_number=1");
}

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        string response = await GetOrdersAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Кстати `amount=100`, вы уверены, что нужно столько? Быть может уменьшение объема запроса ускорит время отклика?

При этом `HttpClient` создается только один раз. То есть самый первый `await GetOrdersAsync()` выполнится как обычно по скорости, а вот все последующие повторные запросы будут отрабатывать почти мгновенно.

Скорость выполнения повторных запросов можно проверить например так

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // нажать любую клавишу, чтобы повторить запрос, нажать Esc для выхода
    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
    {
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
            string response = await GetOrdersAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Запрос выполнен за: {sw.Elapsed}");
    }
}
```